# Is “final intention” a pleonasm?

Tags: writing-style, pleonasms

I'm proofreading a report and stumbled on this in the following form:

> His final intention is to create a large flying city.

Is “final intention” a pleonasm in this sentence (or always)?

Comment: Not necessarily at all. What makes you think so?

Comment: I thought that intention means “goal” in this sentence, and a goal is already an endpoint to some process. Hence I thought a “final endpoint” is a pleonasm.

Comment: intention; noun: 1. a thing intended; an aim or plan. -- Nothing final about it. Furthermore, there's also the concept of an "author's final intention" with a rather different meaning, widely used by editors.

Comment: A “final endpoint” is a pleonasm, but an intention is not an "endpoint" rather a particular "point".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily. His *initial intention* may be to create a large flying city, but his *final intention* may be to fill that city with giant man-eating grasshoppers.

So final intention may not be a pleonasm.

Comment: Thinking alike. Ten seconds apart.

Comment: +1 And his intention is to draw up the plans, and then his intention is to order the material, and then set the first antigravity block and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

No “final intention” is not perissological.  The words do indicate all of his other intentions were a horme to this final purpose